Returning data from a static (non-capturing) lambda
Consider the following method:
static void Invoke<TArg>(Action<TArg> action, TArg arg) => action(arg);

I know; it seems useless, but it's a simplification of the actual code.
Anyway, I need to call Invoke from a method with by-reference parameters, passing a lambda for action. I need some way to return values for the by-reference parameters from inside that lambda. Finally, the lambda must be static (non-capturing).
I've come up with the following wacky scheme:
static unsafe void UpdateFooAndGetBar(ref object foo, out object bar) {
    var args = (foo, bar: (object)null);
    Invoke(
        static pArgs => {
            ref var args = ref Unsafe.AsRef<(object, object)>(pArgs.ToPointer());
            args.Item1 = 123;
            args.Item2 = "baz";
        },
        new IntPtr(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref args))
    );
    foo = args.foo;
    bar = args.bar;
}

That seems to work, but Unsafe makes me nervous. So, is my code legit? Is there a better way?

This smells a bit like an XY problem. It sounds like maybe you're trying to execute some native code from C#. Perhaps Invoke is a stand-in for PInvoke?

Agree that this looks dangerous - the object isn't pinned by anything, so the unmanaged pointer could become invalid; so: why are we using unmanaged pointers here? what is it that you're trying to do that requires them? is the unmanaged pointer here just a trick to get the state in?

Nah, Invoke isn't a stand-in for a native function. Its job is to provide a scope for invoking action – lock scope, logging scope, etc. I know there are simpler and saner ways to do what I'm trying to do, but they're more expensive. The point of the static lambda and value tuple is to minimize heap traffic.

What is the delegate type here? could you not just declare a custom delegate type that takes a ref SomeStruct (possibly with SomeStruct being your value-tuple) and just use that?

Marc, the object is a value tuple – a struct – so it should remain on the stack as long as UpdateFooAndGetBar is running, no?

@BitCortex fair enough, yes; but... personally I'd rather remove the entire need for unmanaged pointers in the first place, and just use a managed pointer so you can Invoke(..., ref args)

@MarcGravell, I'll comment on your answer.

I cannot catch the point. If the action to be called needs to be implemented in this complicated way, why can't it directly accept a byref parameter? This is what I mean: a delegate: delegate void RefAction<T>(ref T) and Invoke: void Invoke<T>(RefAction<T>, ref T)

@shingo Please see Marc Gravell's answer and its comment thread.

Let's assume we have a custom delegate that allows by-ref usage:
delegate void ActionByRef<T>(ref T value);

We can then use that in our Invoke:
static void Invoke<T>(ActionByRef<T> callback, ref T args)
    => callback(ref args); // TODO any other logic

and consume it without any unmanaged pointers:
public static void UpdateFooAndGetBar(ref object foo, out object bar)
{
    var args = (foo, bar: (object)null);
    Invoke(
        static (ref (object foo, object bar) args) => {
            args.Item1 = 123;
            args.Item2 = "baz";
        },
        ref args
    );
    foo = args.foo;
    bar = args.bar;
}

You could also take this a step further by having a custom delegate that matches your exact needs, but that is less reusable:
delegate void RenameThis(ref object foo, out object bar);
//...
static void Invoke(RenameThis callback, ref object foo, out object bar)
    => callback(ref foo, out bar);
//...
public static void UpdateFooAndGetBar(ref object foo, out object bar)
{
    Invoke(
        static (ref object foo, out object bar) => {
            foo = 123;
            bar = "baz";
        },
        ref foo,
        out bar
    );
}


Thanks for your answer. As you suspected, the RenameThis solution isn't practical in my case, as it would require hundreds of Invoke overloads. On the other hand, ActionByRef is an excellent suggestion, although having to specify the lambda parameter type is unfortunate. I'm still curious about the safety of my solution, but I'll accept your answer if nobody can vouch for it :)

@BitCortex re safety: I think your approach is perfectly "safe", and I've seen similar for passing spans into string.Create<TState>(...) (hack needed because you can't normally use a span as generics or in a value-tuple (which is itself generics)

@BitCortex example from the .NET BCL: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/40e664effd1e4d0b62d6f497592eea485ae8d047/src/libraries/Common/src/System/HexConverter.cs#L196 - note they didn't need the extra Unsafe.AsPointer - just used & directly

The compiler doesn't let me use & to take the address of a struct that contains object references. Unsafe.AsPointer allows it, but I found the disagreement between the language and library concerning.

Also, oddly, I needed to convert the pointer to IntPtr because the compiler couldn't infer the Invoke type argument otherwise. Anyway, I think ActionByRef is a fine alternative, so I'm accepting your answer. Thanks again!
